# Override Swagger sorting

Tags: sorting, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

I want to organize my swagger api in reverse alphabetical order but it defaults to alphabetical. Is there a simple way to do this? Specifically using Swashbuckle.Core 5.2.1

Answer (score 1):

You can create a sorter for the UI for both the operations (`operationsSorter`) and tags (`apisSorter`).

Comment: What about using Swashbuckle? I tried using 
c.OrderActionGroupsBy(new CustomStringComparer()); 
but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: It looks like swagger ui defaults to alpha sorting, then what is the point of c.OrderActionGroupsBy()? My Json file is correctly sorted and then Swagger ui seems to be reordering it even though the documentation says it defaults to server sorting

Comment: As of swagger 2.0 I believe it always re-sorts them.  Please open an issue in swagger-ui and we'll make sure you can turn that off

Comment: Ok issue filed https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1763 for swagger-ui and Swashbuckle. 

From the documentation I assumed swagger-ui would default to server ordering. 

"Apply a sort to the API/tags list. It can be 'alpha' (sort by name) or a function (see Array.prototype.sort() to know how sort function works). Default is the order returned by the server unchanged."